# Handler does not get call in MSW test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, msw

I'm trying to set up MSW. I have done all the steps. First I created a `handlers.ts` file like this:

```
import { rest } from 'msw';

import { mockCharacters } from './mockData';

export const handlers = [
  rest.get('gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters/', (req, res, ctx) => {
    console.log('called');
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json(mockCharacters));
  }),
];
```

Then I created the `server.ts` file:

```
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
import { handlers } from './handlers';

export const server = setupServer(...handlers);
```

Then I added the config to the `setupTest.ts` file:

```
// jest-dom adds custom jest matchers for asserting on DOM nodes.
// allows you to do things like:
// expect(element).toHaveTextContent(/react/i)
// learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import { server } from './mocks/server';

// Establish API mocking before all tests.
beforeAll(() => {
  server.listen({
    onUnhandledRequest: 'error',
  });
});

// Reset any request handlers that we may add during the tests,
// so they don't affect other tests.
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());

// Clean up after the tests are finished.
afterAll(() => server.close());
```

The test:

```
function renderWithContext(element: React.ReactElement) {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>{element}</BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}

describe('<Characters/>', () => {
  test('Should render list of characters', async () => {
    renderWithContext(<Characters />);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByText('3-D Man')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
```

But when I run my test the handler never gets called. I know because the `console.log('called');` never shows.

I made sure that the `rest.get('gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters/')` URL is the same I use in my fetch call but I'm using the fetch call inside a `useEffect`.

Comment: I just notice something i changed my fetch method to use fetch insted of axios and it worked how can i configure this to work with axios because i would have to change so much otherwise

Comment: Are you by any chance using `jest.mock('axios')` anywhere?